# Difference between rendering a Function and rendering a Component React/JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've added an example of when I've observed behaviour to be different between the two.
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-snow-siuib

---

If we have a function Component below

```
function MyComponent(){
    return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

What are the differences between the two ways to render it below.

```
//A
function App() {
  return <>{ MyComponent() }</>;
}
```

```
//B
function App(){
    return <MyComponent />
}
```

Is A considered bad practice if so why and are there any reasons to do it?

Comment: your `A` is a syntax error. you probably mean   something like `<>{MyComponent()}</>`. For function components there's no significant difference except for syntax

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I don't think it's true there is no difference the `MyComponent()` version has some different behaviour with hooks.

Comment: Can you show your actual code and what you believe to be the difference?

Comment: It might be that you're accessing something on `props` but you haven't passed any to `MyComponent`, whereas `<MyComponent />` will pass `{}` as props by default `<>` is just short for `React.createElement`

Comment: Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-snow-siuib

Comment: interesting, looks like `createElement` indeed has some involvement with hooks. gonna take a look at the source to see